# Why is a nested struct inside a generic class considered "managed"?

Tags: c#

I have the following simple test:

```
class C<T>
{
    public struct A
    {
        int x;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr p = new IntPtr();

        var a = (C<int>.A*)p.ToPointer();
    }
}
```

The code generates error CS0208:

```
Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed
type ('C<int>.A')
```

Can anyone explain why the struct is considered "managed" in this scenario?

Comment: For the same reason that a generic struct is considered managed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Section 18.2 of the C# 5 spec:

> An unmanaged-type is any type that isn’t a reference-type or constructed type, and doesn’t contain reference-type or constructed type fields at any level of nesting.

Now you might wonder if `C<int>.A` qualifies as a constructed type (its obviously not a reference type). The answer is yes. Section 4.4 defines constructed types. It specifically says nested types are considered constructed. It uses the `Outer<T>.Inner` below as an example:

```
class Outer<T>
{
    public class Inner {...}
    public Inner i;             // Type of i is Outer<T>.Inner
}
```

Comment: An additional point which may or may not be obvious (and isn't directly related to the question) is that `Outer<string>.Inner` is a totally different type than `Outer<int>.Inner` and will generate an error of "Cannot implicitly convert type" if you try to set a variable of one type to a value of the other type.

Comment: The fact that the class is generic may be made more clear by the syntax used by MSIL, namely: "Outer`1/Inner<T>". Specifically the type parameters are all actually at the most nested level. It is possible at the MSIL or reflection.emit level to create a non-generic class nested in Outer<T>, but C# does not permit that, and would porbably have trouble referencing such a type.

Answer (score 7):

Because `T`, which is part of `C` is also part of `A`. Which means `A` is also generic. And all generic types are considered managed.

I guess, it would be possible to check if `A` uses `T` and decide on that. But as with all language features, it is feature, which's implementation would not have much return value.